# Valid JSON without brackets and IDs?

Tags: json

This is a theoretical question. Just wondering why the following is a valid JSON

```
[12,"json",true]
```

There is any answer about that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

THat's a JSON array. According to the [latest specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), all of the following are valid JSON (1 per line):

```
123
"string"
null
true
false
["array item 1", 123]
{ "property": "value" }
```

Answer (score 3):

From [json.org](http://json.org/)

An `array` is an ordered collection of `values`. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

A `value` can be a `string` in double quotes, or a `number`, or `true` or `false` or `null`, or an `object` or an `array`. These structures can be nested.

Hence `[12,"json",true]` is a valid json.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as definied in [RFC 7159 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html#section-5):

> An array structure is represented as square brackets surrounding
> zero    or more values (or elements).  Elements are separated by
> commas.
>
> array = begin-array [ value *( value-separator value ) ] end-array
>
> There is no requirement that the values in an array be of the same
> type.